# Dividing a Rails edit view for the purposes of UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

So I have a 'Project' model which respective db table has many attributes.

Ideally, when I hit `projects/1/edit`, I'd like the user to:

1. See and be able to edit only a portion of the project attributes
2. See a navigation menu that allows her to navigate to another view that allows to see and edit the attributes left.

All this instead of showing all the attributes in one 'edit' view.

I'm leaning to a JS solution that hides and shows specific attributes when a menu is clicked. However, I'd ideally want that the urls reflect the section the user is located for example:

Instead of a url like `projects/1/edit` I'd like something like:
`projects/1/edit/name_of_section_1` and `projects/1/edit/name_of_section_2`

In any case I wonder what would be the best practice when it comes to divide views like this.

**UPDATE: Only a few precisions/revisions from Dan's solution below for future reference**

I've used his second approach successfully revising his proposed code as follows:

**Config/routes.rb** 
*revised the controller name for both routes to 'projects'*

```
resources :projects do
    member do
      get "settings/:panel" => "projects#edit", as: :settings
      patch "settings/:panel/update" => "projects#update", as: :update_settings
    end
end
```

**Controllers/projects_controller.rb**
*There was some mistake in the proposed code for the edit action so I slightly changed it to make it work*

```
  def edit
    panel = ['general', 'invitations', 'welcome_message', 'danger'].detect{|p| p == params[:panel] }
    render template: "projects/#{panel}.html.erb" if panel
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this and there all equally valid. 
If you need all the fields filled in to create the record you'll either need to have tabbed views with javascript (bootstrap has a nice plugin for this)

To do this with custom routes you could have:

`resources :projects do
  member do
    get "settings"
    patch "update_settings"
    get "settings2"
    patch "update_settings2"
  end
end`

which would give you URLs like `/projects/1/settings` and `projects/1/update_settings`

If you have lots of panels you could do this more efficiently with something like this:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get "settings/:panel" => "settings#edit" as: :settings
    patch "settings/:panel/update" => "settings#update" as: :update_settings
  end
end
```

to allow for routes like `/projects/1/settings/page1` and `/projects/1/settings/page2`

in your controller you could then have:

```
def edit
  if panel = ['page1', 'page2'].detect{|p| p == params[:panel] }
    render template: panel
  end
end
```

this checks ifs its a valid panel you've made and then renders that specific template you've created in app/view/projects/page1.html.erb

Comment: Dan, thanks a lot for your reply. Please let me give it a try and come back to you. I think I need to give it a try to undertsand clearly the solution. I'll let you know soon how it goes

Comment: Dan, I've tried your second approach with success. Thanks a lot. I'm still getting the hang of Rails and sometimes confused with how to setup routes, so you saved me time!
I've just updated my question to reflect some revisions I had to made to your code to make it work. If something doesn't sound right to you. Let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Sweet as. Revisions sounds about right. It was dinner time when I was writing it and my wife was giving me that look that said "hurry up". Feel free to accept it as the answer and I'll be a happy man :)

Comment: Great, no worries. Thanks again and one extra point for taking the time to answer a question no other people felt like answering!!